# Ignore files when use core.worktree

Tags: git

I created a git repo:

```
mkdir ~/configs
cd ~/configs
git init
git config core.worktree "../../"
echo "*" > .gitignore
```

But files are not ignored:

```
git status    
Sur la branche master

Validation initiale

Fichiers non suivis:
  (utilisez "git add <fichier>..." pour inclure dans ce qui sera validé)

    ../.ICEauthority
    ../.Skype/
    ../.VirtualBox/
    [...]
```

How ignore files when use `git config core.worktree` ?

Answer (score 4):

Your .gitignore file will work better at the root of your git work tree.

Consider..

```
echo "*" > ../../.gitignore
```

When you are separating your git-dir and work-tree, I normally recommend you create a `bare` git repo, though this can make it seem more complex.

Also consider the following **instead** of  using .gitignore.

```
# git config status.showUntrackedFiles no
# git config status.relativePaths false
```

The `showUntrackedFiles=no` tells git to report only on changes to tracked files, and not untracked files.  It also removes the need to use `-f`
every time you feel a need to add a new file to the repository. Another advantage is you can override the `showUntrackedFiles` setting on the fly with `git status -u`.

The `relativePaths` option is handy (I find). git status will use absolute paths when reporting file status.  Since the working directory is outside the git directory, I find this to be a clearer view of what has changed.

Lastly, when you want to do commits, you will find you have to keep using CD to go to the git directory.  Try

```
# export GIT_DIR=/path/to/.git
# git status
```

To avoid having a fixed `GIT_DIR` in my shell environment, I normally wrap this in an alias so the `GIT_DIR` is only set for the specific instance of `git`;

```
# alias gitc='GIT_DIR=/path/to/.git git'
# gitc status
```

This will allow you to manage the git repository from anywhere, even outside the work tree.  It also works extremely well with the `bare` repository I referred to above.

HTH

Comment: Thanks ! I will use your bare repo idea. Before i accept your answer: ```echo * > ../../.gitignore``` don't work. ```echo "*" > ../.gitignore``` working.

Answer (score 0):

From the [git documentation for gitignore](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore#_description):

> - Patterns read from $GIT_DIR/info/exclude.

So all you need to do is treat the "info/exclude" file like it's a `.gitignore` file at the root of your worktree.